# Problems with Audio Drivers in SSH Session

Tags: sound, ssh, alsa

I'm having an interesting problem with my audio drivers when doing ssh/X-window's forwarding.

Basically ALSA works fine locally, but if I use a program that needs to access alsa over ssh I get the following error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1041:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

(I'm using the speaker-test program to test this).

I don't care if the sound plays locally or on the server, but I do need the sound driver to work.

Comment: ALSA tries to access the hardware on the machine where you're executing stuff. Check `ls -l /dev/snd/` for permissions.

Comment: Thanks apparently my local user wasn't in the audio group

Comment: Please write an answer with how exactly you determined this, and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out my problem was that my local user wasn't in the audio group.

```
$ groups
user adm dialout cdrom plugdev fuse lpadmin admin sambashare vboxusers subversion
```

But the /dev/snd devices where owned by the audio group

```
$ls -la /dev/snd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root      480 Mar 13 21:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root     5020 Mar 13 21:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       80 Mar 13 21:03 by-id
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      120 Mar 13 21:03 by-path
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 10 Feb 24 21:48 controlC0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  2 Feb 24 21:48 controlC1
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 16 Mar  2 23:44 controlC2
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 18 Mar 13 21:03 controlC3
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 15 Feb 24 21:48 hwC0D2
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  9 Feb 24 21:48 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 12 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 11 Feb 25 22:46 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 13 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 14 Feb 24 21:48 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  7 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC1D10p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  8 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC1D11p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  3 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  4 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  5 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  6 Feb 24 21:49 pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 17 Mar  6 22:19 pcmC2D0p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 19 Mar 13 21:43 pcmC3D0c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  1 Feb 24 21:48 seq
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 33 Feb 24 21:48 timer
```

Interestingly this didn't seem to be causing problems locally, even though it probably should have been. To fix it I simply added my user to the audio group and then loged out and back in again (from my local session NOT the ssh session)